# Select value only with letter is starting letter in autocomplete datalist

Tags: html

I am using **datalist** for my **autocomplete** field. Its working fine. I have the values **james,reeta and mary** in my list, if i enter **"r"** in my auto complete box, it returns the values reeta and mary because mary also contain the letter **"r"**. but i dont want my auto complete to work like this. i just want only **reeta not mary** it means the values which has the entered letter as the starting letter.

Comment: I found it weird that autocomplete datalist works as you demanded i.e. on entering 'r' it shows only reeta and not marry in Chrome and IE-10 (Lower version of IE doesn't support datalist) while only Mozilla Firefox displayed both reeta and mary on hitting 'r'. Please share if you figured out that whats the reason behind this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `source` option to implement your own search:

```
var dataSource = ['mary', 'reeta', 'james'];

$("input").autocomplete({
    minLength: 1,
    source: function(request, response) {

        var matcher = new RegExp( '^' + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
        var filteredData = $.grep( dataSource, function(value) {
            return matcher.test( value.label || value.value || value );
        });
        response(filteredData);
    }
});
```

example http://jsfiddle.net/AU92X/8/

Or you can even make it global just by rewriting `$.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex`:

```
var dataSource = ['mary', 'reeta', 'james'];

$("input").autocomplete({
    minLength: 1,
    source: dataSource
});

var escapeRegexp = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex;
$.extend( $.ui.autocomplete, {
    escapeRegex: function( value ) {
        return '^' + escapeRegexp(value);
    }
});
```

example http://jsfiddle.net/AU92X/10/

Comment: Hi claustrofob, Its working fine for me... Thank u so much... I used $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex function... Thanks a lot..

Comment: @SangeethaKrishnan just noticed that the question was about html5 datalist=) Glad that my answer helped.

Comment: ya but i dropped the idea with data list.. i just used autocomplete without datalist as u said...