# Prevent filtering autocomplete suggestions in a <input type="search"> tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html input field that is connected to a datalist containing suggestions for autocompletion.

```
<input type="search" id="input-search" class="form-control" name="searchfield" list="autocompleteitems">

<datalist id="autocompleteitems">
</datalist>
```

the datalist gets its content through javascript ajax calls when a key is pressed in the search bar.
My autocomplete suggestions contain also synonyms which i want to display. That leads to a problem showed in the following example. Assuming i want to search for "apple" and type `ap` ìnto the search bar. The ajax request gets a result list and puts it in my datalist as follows:

```
<datalist id="autocompleteitems">
    <option value="apple"></option>
    <option value="fruit"></option>
    <option value="apples"></option>
</datalist>
```

What i want is a suggestion with those three items (apple, fruit apples). Because `fruit` does not start with `ap`it gets kicked out and only `apple`and `apples`is suggested.

Is there a way to prevent html/the browser from filtering those items not starting with the text in the searchbox?

**Edit**
The stackoverflow post linked in the comment shows how to set a filter on a search field. But firefox does filter automatically and my question is how to **not filter** the results.

**Example:**

I type `ap` into the search field.

My ajax request returns `apple` and `fruit` and writes that in the datalist.

Now firefox suggests `apple`, but throws `fruit` away because it does not start with `ap`.

What I want is that both words are suggestet - `apple` and `fruit`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select value only with letter is starting letter in autocomplete datalist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17192883/select-value-only-with-letter-is-starting-letter-in-autocomplete-datalist)

Comment: @BanujanBalendrakumar Thanks for your answer, basically with the autocomplete function of jquery-ui i could get this to work. Better would be a solution to invoke the filtering using just basic jquery functionality. Optimal would be a flag i could set in the input tag, but i doubt that exists...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41678677/avoid-filtering-of-datalist-items-in-an-input-element

Comment: @epascarello I wanted to avoid using `jquery-ui.js` as an extra library to include. But if thats the only way to go i'll do that. Thanks.

Comment: I mean you can code your own and not use a library

Comment: `<option value="fruit">apple</option>` is an option, but not exactly what you wanted.

Comment: @epascarello. If i do that, the choosen autocompletion-value would be different from the displayed one. So its not really a solution.

Answer (score -2):

RegEx in Java Script might help u https://javascript.info/regexp-anchors.
you can have a JS function for this inside your HTML.

Once u get the filtered values from your data list,
check them with a regular expression.

**Example:**

```js
var filtered_Recs_From_DataList = "Apple";
console.log( /^Apple/.test(filtered_Recs_From_DataList) );
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: How is a regexp going to help with autocomplete? I think you misread thhe question