# How to show only results with exact matched?

Tags: select, startswith, vue-select

I'm using vue-select (https://vue-select.org/). By default it returns all results that includes the searching text. I only want to display results that starts with the entered text. Is there an option to change it?
For example

```
options:
[
'abc',
'cba',
'avx',
'bca'
]

searching text:
'a'

results: 
[
'abc',
'avx'
]
```

So I want to make sth like this: [Select value only with letter is starting letter in autocomplete datalist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17192883/select-value-only-with-letter-is-starting-letter-in-autocomplete-datalist)

Answer (score 0):

You could check the documentation it has `filter` prop

https://vue-select.org/guide/filtering.html#filtering-with-fuse-js